# Failing to scrape data from webpage using JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, scrape

My problem is: scrape the curse price (8875.53) out of the webpage.

```
       <span class="inst-rate">8875.53</span>
```

But my way failed. Does somebody know what's my mistake?

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
    public class JavaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Document doc= 
    Jsoup.connect("https://www.plus500.de/Instruments/BTCUSD").get();
    Elements element =doc.select(".inst-rate");
    System.out.println(element); 
     }
    }
```

Console output: `<span class="inst-rate" v-text="BuyPrice"></span>`

Comment: * conole output is:<span class="inst-rate" v-text="BuyPrice"></span>

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the text of the element: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Probably element.text() is what you need

Answer (score 0):

The text in this tag in not part of initial html, but is set by JavaScript after page is loaded. You can check it by disabling JavaScript in your browser. Jsoup only gets static html, does not execute JavaScript code.

When you examine what connections are made from the page you will find out that the value is updated through request to this API:

https://www.plus500.de/api/LiveData/FeedUpdate?instrumentId=3406

Make a request to this url, parser result and you will get desired value.